# Room CHECK constraint failed: Vehicle (Sqlite code 275 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_CHECK) (OS error - 11

Tags: android, constraints, android-room, database-migration, check-constraints

I'm stuck with the problem for hours... I got a simple entity class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "Vehicle",
        indices = {@Index(value = {"vehicleName"},unique = true),
                @Index(value = {"brandId"}),
                @Index(value = {"ownerId"})},
        foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(entity=Brand.class, parentColumns="id", childColumns="brandId", onDelete = SET_DEFAULT),
                       @ForeignKey(entity=Driver.class, parentColumns="id", childColumns="ownerId", onDelete = SET_DEFAULT),
        }
)
public class Vehicle implements Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @NotNull
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "vehicleType")
    @TypeConverters(Converters.class)
    @NotNull
    private VehicleType vehicleType;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "vehicleName")
    @NotNull
    private String vehicleName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "distanceUnit")
    @TypeConverters(Converters.class)
    @NotNull
    private DistanceUnit distanceUnit;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "currencyUnit")
    @TypeConverters(Converters.class)
    @NotNull
    private Currency currencyUnit;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "mainFuelTank")
    @TypeConverters(Converters.class)
    @NotNull
    private FuelTank mainFuelTank;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "secondFuelTank")
    @TypeConverters(Converters.class)
    private FuelTank secondFuelTank;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "vehiclePic")
    private String vehiclePic;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "brandId")
    private int brandId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "modelName")
    private String modelName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "buildYear")
    @TypeConverters(Converters.class)
    private Date buildYear;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "ownerId")
    private int ownerId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "licensePlate")
    private String licensePlate;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "vinNumber")
    private String vinNumber;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "note")
    private String note;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "isActive",  defaultValue = "1")
    @NotNull
    private boolean isActive;


    @ColumnInfo(name = "customVehicleProps")
    @TypeConverters(Converters.class)
    private Map<String,String> customVehicleProps;


    public Vehicle(VehicleType vehicleType, @NotNull String vehicleName, @NotNull DistanceUnit distanceUnit, @NotNull Currency currencyUnit, @NotNull FuelTank mainFuelTank) {
        this.vehicleType = vehicleType;
        this.vehicleName = vehicleName;
        this.distanceUnit = distanceUnit;
        this.currencyUnit = currencyUnit;
        this.mainFuelTank = mainFuelTank;
        customVehicleProps = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        setIsActive(true);
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public VehicleType getVehicleType() {
        return vehicleType;
    }

    public void setVehicleType(VehicleType vehicleType) {
        this.vehicleType = vehicleType;
    }

    @NotNull
    public String getVehicleName() {
        return vehicleName;
    }

    public void setVehicleName(@NotNull String vehicleName) {
        this.vehicleName = vehicleName;
    }

    @NotNull
    public DistanceUnit getDistanceUnit() {
        return distanceUnit;
    }

    public void setDistanceUnit(@NotNull DistanceUnit distanceUnit) {
        this.distanceUnit = distanceUnit;
    }

    @NotNull
    public Currency getCurrencyUnit() {
        return currencyUnit;
    }

    public void setCurrencyUnit(@NotNull Currency currencyUnit) {
        this.currencyUnit = currencyUnit;
    }


    @NotNull
    public FuelTank getMainFuelTank() {
        return mainFuelTank;
    }

    public void setMainFuelTank(@NotNull FuelTank mainFuelTank) {
        this.mainFuelTank = mainFuelTank;
    }

    public FuelTank getSecondFuelTank() {
        return secondFuelTank;
    }

    public void setSecondFuelTank(FuelTank secondFuelTank) {
        this.secondFuelTank = secondFuelTank;
    }

    public String getVehiclePic() {
        return vehiclePic;
    }

    public void setVehiclePic(String vehiclePic) {
        this.vehiclePic = vehiclePic;
    }

    public int getBrandId() {
        return brandId;
    }

    public void setBrandId(int brandId) {
        this.brandId = brandId;
    }

    public String getModelName() {
        return modelName;
    }

    public void setModelName(String modelName) {
        this.modelName = modelName;
    }

    public Date getBuildYear() {
        return buildYear;
    }

    public void setBuildYear(Date buildYear) {
        this.buildYear = buildYear;
    }

    public int getOwnerId() {
        return ownerId;
    }

    public void setOwnerId(int ownerId) {
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
    }

    public String getLicensePlate() {
        return licensePlate;
    }

    public void setLicensePlate(String licensePlate) {
        this.licensePlate = licensePlate;
    }

    public String getVinNumber() {
        return vinNumber;
    }

    public void setVinNumber(String vinNumber) {
        this.vinNumber = vinNumber;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public boolean getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }


    public Map<String, String> getCustomVehicleProps() {
        return customVehicleProps;
    }

    public void setCustomVehicleProps(Map<String, String> customVehicleProps) {
        this.customVehicleProps = customVehicleProps;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Vehicle vehicle = (Vehicle) o;
        return getId() == vehicle.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }

    public void addCustomProperty(String key, String prop){
        customVehicleProps.put(key,prop);
    }

    public void removeCustomProperty(String key){
        customVehicleProps.remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vehicle{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", vehicleType=" + vehicleType +
                ", vehicleName='" + vehicleName + '\'' +
                ", distanceUnit=" + distanceUnit +
                ", currencyUnit=" + currencyUnit +
                ", mainFuelTank=" + mainFuelTank +
                ", secondFuelTank=" + secondFuelTank +
                ", vehiclePic='" + vehiclePic + '\'' +
                ", brandId=" + brandId +
                ", modelName='" + modelName + '\'' +
                ", buildYear=" + buildYear +
                ", ownerId=" + ownerId +
                ", licensePlate='" + licensePlate + '\'' +
                ", vinNumber='" + vinNumber + '\'' +
                ", note='" + note + '\'' +
                ", isActive=" + isActive +
                ", customVehicleProps=" + customVehicleProps +
                '}';
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(this.id);
        dest.writeInt(this.vehicleType == null ? -1 : this.vehicleType.ordinal());
        dest.writeString(this.vehicleName);
        dest.writeInt(this.distanceUnit == null ? -1 : this.distanceUnit.ordinal());
        dest.writeSerializable(this.currencyUnit);
        dest.writeParcelable(this.mainFuelTank, flags);
        dest.writeParcelable(this.secondFuelTank, flags);
        dest.writeString(this.vehiclePic);
        dest.writeInt(this.brandId);
        dest.writeString(this.modelName);
        dest.writeLong(this.buildYear != null ? this.buildYear.getTime() : -1);
        dest.writeInt(this.ownerId);
        dest.writeString(this.licensePlate);
        dest.writeString(this.vinNumber);
        dest.writeString(this.note);
        dest.writeByte(this.isActive ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
        dest.writeInt(this.customVehicleProps.size());
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : this.customVehicleProps.entrySet()) {
            dest.writeString(entry.getKey());
            dest.writeString(entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void readFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        this.id = source.readInt();
        int tmpVehicleType = source.readInt();
        this.vehicleType = tmpVehicleType == -1 ? null : VehicleType.values()[tmpVehicleType];
        this.vehicleName = source.readString();
        int tmpDistanceUnit = source.readInt();
        this.distanceUnit = tmpDistanceUnit == -1 ? null : DistanceUnit.values()[tmpDistanceUnit];
        this.currencyUnit = (Currency) source.readSerializable();
        this.mainFuelTank = source.readParcelable(FuelTank.class.getClassLoader());
        this.secondFuelTank = source.readParcelable(FuelTank.class.getClassLoader());
        this.vehiclePic = source.readString();
        this.brandId = source.readInt();
        this.modelName = source.readString();
        long tmpBuildYear = source.readLong();
        this.buildYear = tmpBuildYear == -1 ? null : new Date(tmpBuildYear);
        this.ownerId = source.readInt();
        this.licensePlate = source.readString();
        this.vinNumber = source.readString();
        this.note = source.readString();
        this.isActive = source.readByte() != 0;
        int customVehiclePropsSize = source.readInt();
        this.customVehicleProps = new HashMap<String, String>(customVehiclePropsSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < customVehiclePropsSize; i++) {
            String key = source.readString();
            String value = source.readString();
            this.customVehicleProps.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    protected Vehicle(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readInt();
        int tmpVehicleType = in.readInt();
        this.vehicleType = tmpVehicleType == -1 ? null : VehicleType.values()[tmpVehicleType];
        this.vehicleName = in.readString();
        int tmpDistanceUnit = in.readInt();
        this.distanceUnit = tmpDistanceUnit == -1 ? null : DistanceUnit.values()[tmpDistanceUnit];
        this.currencyUnit = (Currency) in.readSerializable();
        this.mainFuelTank = in.readParcelable(FuelTank.class.getClassLoader());
        this.secondFuelTank = in.readParcelable(FuelTank.class.getClassLoader());
        this.vehiclePic = in.readString();
        this.brandId = in.readInt();
        this.modelName = in.readString();
        long tmpBuildYear = in.readLong();
        this.buildYear = tmpBuildYear == -1 ? null : new Date(tmpBuildYear);
        this.ownerId = in.readInt();
        this.licensePlate = in.readString();
        this.vinNumber = in.readString();
        this.note = in.readString();
        this.isActive = in.readByte() != 0;
        int customVehiclePropsSize = in.readInt();
        this.customVehicleProps = new HashMap<String, String>(customVehiclePropsSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < customVehiclePropsSize; i++) {
            String key = in.readString();
            String value = in.readString();
            this.customVehicleProps.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Vehicle> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Vehicle>() {
        @Override
        public Vehicle createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Vehicle(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Vehicle[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Vehicle[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Corresponding migration code:

```
database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Vehicle");
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Vehicle(" +
    "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
    "vehicleName TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL," +
    "distanceUnit TEXT  NOT NULL CHECK(distanceUnit = \"KM\" or distanceUnit = \"MILES\") ," +
    "currencyUnit TEXT  NOT NULL," +
    "mainFuelTank TEXT  NOT NULL," +
    "secondFuelTank TEXT," +
    "vehiclePic TEXT," +
    "modelName TEXT," +
    "licensePlate TEXT," +
    "vinNumber TEXT," +
    "note TEXT," +
    "isActive INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 CHECK(isActive IN (0,1))," +
    "customVehicleProps TEXT," +
    "buildYear INTEGER," +
    "ownerId INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
    "brandId INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
    "vehicleType TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(vehicleType = \"MOTORCYCLE\" or vehicleType = \"CAR\" or vehicleType = \"TRUCK\" or vehicleType = \"BUS\")," +
    "FOREIGN KEY(\"ownerId\") REFERENCES \"Driver\"(\"id\") ON DELETE SET DEFAULT,"+
    "FOREIGN KEY(\"brandId\") REFERENCES \"Brand\"(\"id\") ON DELETE SET DEFAULT)");
```

As you can, I've got 2-3 check constraints not not allow dummy values.
BUT If I try adding an object which has the RIGHT Properties.
e.g

```
Vehicle{id=0, vehicleType=CAR, vehicleName='Audi', distanceUnit=KM, currencyUnit=NAD, mainFuelTank=FuelTank{fuelType=LIQUIDS, maxFuelAmount=50.0, volumeUnit=LITER}, secondFuelTank=null, 
vehiclePic='null', brandId=1, modelName='', buildYear=null, ownerId=1, licensePlate='', vinNumber='', note='', isActive=true, customVehicleProps={=}}
```

I receive a CONSTRAINT Error, which does not make any sense for me, cause distanceUnit, isActive, vehicleType is correct constraint and the primary key is also autoincrement so I should not be worried about that.
What can the issue be?
I made sure that I had each converter class for the ENUMS for distanceUnit and vehicleType.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: CHECK constraint failed: Vehicle (Sqlite code 275 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_CHECK), (OS error - 11:Try again)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:923)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:810)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeInsert(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:51)
at androidx.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insertAndReturnId(EntityInsertionAdapter.java:114)
at com.example.dochjavatestimplementation.pkgBAO.CarServiceDao_CarServiceDB_Impl$18.call(CarServiceDao_CarServiceDB_Impl.java:543)
at com.example.dochjavatestimplementation.pkgBAO.CarServiceDao_CarServiceDB_Impl$18.call(CarServiceDao_CarServiceDB_Impl.java:538)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFromCallable.subscribeActual(SingleFromCallable.java:44)
at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```

My Converters look like this:

```
    @TypeConverter
public static DistanceUnit fromStringToDistanceUnit(String value) {
    Type listType = new TypeToken<DistanceUnit>() {}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(value, listType);
}

@TypeConverter
public static String fromDistanceUnitToString(DistanceUnit dUnit) {
    
    return dUnit.toString();
}


@TypeConverter
public static VehicleType fromStringToVehicleType(String value) {
    Type listType = new TypeToken<VehicleType>() {}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(value, listType);
}
@TypeConverter
public static String fromVehicleTypeToString(VehicleType vt) {
    return gson.toJson(vt);
}
```

Comment: Could you add your stack trace to the question?

Comment: @CommonsWare I've added the stacktrace in my current edit.

Comment: "As you can, I've got 2-3 check constraints not not allow dummy values" -- where are those being set up by annotations on your `@Entity`? If the answer is "they are not", that's not a good idea. Beyond that, my best guess is that there is a mismatch between what `Converters` does and what those `CHECK` constraints are doing.

Comment: @CommonsWare thx for the answer. Conserning Converters, there should not be an issue cause I used the same principle for other entity classes (see converters as edit). Oh ok, cause I tought its enough to check the constraint in the database, as at the end of the day, the truly correct data is always within the database and it couldnt get pass through the sqllite checkconstraint

Comment: "there should not be an issue cause I used the same principle for other entity classes (see converters as edit" -- you are generating JSON. Your `CHECK` constraints do not seem set up for that. "the truly correct data is always within the database and it couldnt get pass through the sqllite checkconstraint" -- the problem is that you only have `CHECK` for users who go through that migration. New users will not need that migration, and Room is not going to add `CHECK` constraints. So now you have two different schemas, depending on whether the user went through your migration or not.

Comment: If you want to be in charge of the schema, that is fine, but then you should be looking at [SQLDelight](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight) instead of Room. With SQLDelight, you control the schema, and the library generates classes for you. With Room, you control the classes, and the library generates the schema for you. If you wish to stick with Room, your migrations should set up the database to match what Room generates for new users.

Comment: @CommonsWare ty so much for the answer. I'll check SQLDelight out. and check if the json string is also valid :)